# I have bought a new wireless card and I have the same problem , it connects then it isn't able to browse anything

Tags: wireless, networking, ubuntu-bug

I can connect with wired connection in my living room but I can't with my wireless card.
I'm pretty sure card is ok because I got a new one and driver works fine.
I had Ubuntu 12.04 then I downgraded it to 11.10 and I have the same problem over and over again.
I searched all over the forums and I can't find an answer.

```
 ifconfig
   :eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:35:11:b0  
      inet addr:192.168.2.6  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:fe35:11b0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3930 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3959080 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:591022 (591.0 KB)
      Interrupt:43 Base address:0x6000 

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:d1:11:12:af:79  
      inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fad1:11ff:fe12:af79/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4872 (4.8 KB)  TX bytes:30698 (30.6 KB)
```

nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        40:61:86:35:11:B0

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.2.6
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.2.1

    DNS:             192.168.2.1


- Device: wlan0  [bitches] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k_htc
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        F8:D1:11:12:AF:79

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           7 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
   WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *bitches:        Infra, CC:5D:4E:DD:33:D0, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength     100 WPA WPA2
*hteronet:       Infra, CC:5D:4E:DD:33:D0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA WPA2
```

IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.2.5
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.2.1

```
DNS:             192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `nm-tool`

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Can we assume that DNS server works? Are you able to ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Yes im able to ping it,and no i cant change resolve because system modifies it every time i change it

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server isn't working properly. You have a few options.

1. Get your DNS server at 192.168.2.1 working properly
2. Change your router/DHCP server to give out an address to a DNS server that is working properly
3. Change your computer to use a DNS server that is working properly.

As #1 and #2 aren't Ubuntu specific, I'll give more detail on #3. The system changes resolv.conf because in 12.04 resolv.conf is not generated.

To add a static DNS server, first you need to edit your network connections.

[image: Edit network connections]

Next, edit the wired connection

[image: Edit wired connection]

Next set it to only get an IP address from DHCP

[image: Addresses only]

Last, enter a working DNS server. 8.8.8.8 is a google DNS server that you can use. If you want to add multiple DNS servers here then just separate the IP addresses with a comma.

[image: Add DNS]

Once you've added the DNS servers, click save until you get back to the desktop. You should then be able to browse the internet.

Comment: Hey,my wired connection is fine.wireless isnt working. Its probably 1 or 2

Comment: So go to the wireless tab instead and do the same thing for the network that isn't working

Comment: It isnt working,im so frustrated by this

Comment: So if you manually place 8.8.8.8 into resolv.conf does it work? That would at least let us know we're working in the right direction.